# Do I need Indexing required in case of less data returned by DynamoDb

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

Say, the dynamo db has data of format:-

```
{
"id":"<id>", 
"field-1":"<field-1-value>",
"field-2":"<field-2-value>",
"field-3":"<field-3-value>",
"field-4":"<field-4-value>",
"metadata":{
        "subfield-1":"<subfield-1-value>",
        "subfield-2":"<subfield-2-value>"
        }
}
```

So, I have a partition key on id column and sort key on field-1 say. Now, say, I have a requirement that for the same id, if we want a search capability on subfield-1 value, so can that be easily done in Dynamo Db without creating any index. The max. number of rows that would be there for each id would be 70. So, looks like a small set of data.

Please let me know your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved without index. You can use `FilterExpression` to filter the data i.e. `metadata.subfield-1`.

**Example:**

```
var params = {
    TableName : 'yourTableName',
    KeyConditionExpression : 'id = :idval', 
    FilterExpression : '#metadata = :subField1Val',
     ExpressionAttributeNames : {
        '#metadata' : 'metadata.subfield-1'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':idval' : '7',
        'subField1Val' : 'somevalue'

    }
};
```